# Symfony 3.3 - Validation without form

Tags: php, api, symfony, validation

I am trying to perform some validation for some query string parameters that were passed in. I want to do 3 things:

1. Check if firstname was passed.
2. If it was passed, validate that it is a string. Otherwise, throw an error.
3. If it isn't passed, assign a default name.

I want to re-use as much of the built-in Symfony validator functionality to do this and so far have something like the code below (but it is not working). Would anyone have suggestions?

Relevant References:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type
```

Code:

```
public function testingAction(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = $request->query->all();
   // for this example, assume that $parameters contains 'firstname'=>123

   $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
      'firstname' => new Type(array('type'=>'string'))
   );

   $errors = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($parameters, $collectionConstraint);

   return new Response('<html><body><pre>' . print_r($errors, TRUE) . '</pre></body></html>');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Symfony validation works on entity class. You need to create an entity class for your data with validation annotations.

```
// src/Entity/Author.php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $name;
}
```

//then use this class for your data

```
use src/Entity/Auther.php;
public function testingAction(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = $request->query->all();
    $auther = new Auther();
    $auther->setName($paramater['name']);
    $errors = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($auther);

   return new Response('<html><body><pre>' . print_r($errors, TRUE) . '</pre></body></html>');
}
```

Please follow the symfony link https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: Thank you for the example Vikash. I think that this is a good way of doing things. However, in our situation, not every parameter passed as a query string into our REST API is necessarily going to map to a field in the database. In some cases, it might (like firstname, lastname, etc.). But, in other cases, we are allowing the user to pass a query string like ?limit=50 (to indicate they only want to see 50 records). We don't have a limit field in our Entity class, but we have ones for firstname, lastname, etc. So, would you know of a way to also incorporate this requirement into your solution?

Comment: Also, above, you are creating a instance of an Entity class and then setting the name parameter, and then calling the validate function on the Entity. 90% of our REST API actions will be read-only actions where the client is just requesting data (and then, they can filter by adding query string parameters). In this instance, it seems odd to be setting properties on the Entity class when in fact, we won't be writing/persisting that data back to the database. Though I can see that the reason you have done this is to be able to validate. Is this still the best solution given the requirements?